# Bootstrap panel issues - Panel heading not full width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with 4 bootstrap panels that is supposed to be a basic walk-through.

My requirements:

- The panels must be side by side for a large screen, but they must be responsive, and as the screen gets smaller and switch to vertical orientation.
- The panels must all be the same height
- The panels must have a proper heading bar

The issue I am getting right now is that I can solve the first two with the code below, but that leaves the panels with the weird heading that does not extend all the way across the panel as shown below.

[image: Weird Panel Headings]

Here is the code I have the is generating this problem.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h3>Title!</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="flexbox">

        <div id="box1" class="panel panel-default panel-wizard col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Step 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p> Blah. Blah....</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="box2" class="panel panel-default panel-wizard col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Step 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                 Blah. Blah....
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="box3" class="panel panel-default panel-wizard col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Step 3</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                 Blah. Blah....                    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="box4" class="panel panel-default panel-wizard col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Step 4</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                 Blah. Blah....
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.panel-wizard {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fhnzaz3L/)

It seems that anything I do to try and fix the issue with the panel headings violates another one of my requirements.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fhnzaz3L/1/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `col-lg-3` has a left and right padding by default

try this

```
 .flexbox .col-lg-3{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right:0;
    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fhnzaz3L/2/)**